# Shift all elements in a 2-dimensional array by column index

Tags: java, arrays

How to shift 2-dimensional array from index position

```
int[][] x = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
    };

index = 3

int[][] y = 
        {
            { 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
        };
```

Any Idea? thanks

Comment: `Any Idea?` - Java Code will do

Comment: try writing some thoughts down - even on paper

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. Please go through the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. This is not the kind of question that the community expects.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to StackOverflow. @IshitaSinha

Comment: Take a 1-dimensional array with 3 elements and shift it by 1. Then expand on that to solve your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program uses a logic in which we rotate an array by reversing array in parts. First we will reverse array upto index location and then reverse remaining array ( index+1 to last element of array).
After completing above two steps we call again reverse function but this time on whole of the array that gives us the required output.

Below is the code that will help in understanding above logic described.

```
public class ShiftTwoDArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] x = {   { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 } 
                    };

        int index = 3;
        int i, j;
        // System.out.println(x.length);
        System.out.println("Before");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(x[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        rotate(x, index);

        System.out.println("\nAfter");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(x[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param x
     * @param index
     * calls rotateUtil on each row
     */
    private static void rotate(int[][] x, int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            rotateUtil(x[i], index);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param x
     * @param index
     * reverse array in parts and then reverse whole array
     */
    private static void rotateUtil(int[] x, int index) {
        reverse(x, 0, index);
        reverse(x, index + 1, x.length - 1);
        reverse(x, 0, x.length - 1);
    }

    /**
     * @param x
     * @param start
     * @param end
     * reverse an array
     */
    private static void reverse(int[] x, int start, int end) {
        int temp = 0;
        while (start < end) {
            temp = x[start];
            x[start] = x[end];
            x[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mook You might want to look up "simple" in a dictionary.

Comment: @mook : The code is lengthy a bit but its not complicated. For the purpose of simplicity, different functions have been provided so that logic can be explained separately.

Comment: @Rehan : I am glad, it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, using Guava and Java 8:

```
Arrays.stream(x)
        .map(Ints::asList)
        .forEach(list -> Collections.rotate(list, index));
```

Or the Java 7 version:

```
for (int[] array : x) {
    Collections.rotate(Ints.asList(array), index);
}
```

Comment: @mook Wrong on both counts.

Comment: @mook [com.google.common.primitives.Ints](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html)

Comment: @mook it definitely is in the answer. And if you happen to use the library (as *many* do), I think it's quite an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
int[][] x = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
              { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
              { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
              { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 } };

int index = 3;

// Create 2D array of matching size
int[][] y = new int[x.length][x[0].length];

// Loop through each row of x
for (int r = 0; r < x.length; r++) {
    // Loop through each column of x[r][]
    for (int c = 0; c < x[0].length; c++) {
        // Put x's value in y, shifting to the right by index.
        // See comment outside of code regarding %
        y[r][(c + index) % x[0].length] = x[r][c];
    }
}

// Print out y to see if it worked
for (int r = 0; r < y.length; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < y[0].length; c++) {
        System.out.print(y[r][c] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The key here is the `% x[0].length` in `y[r][(c + index) % x[0].length] = x[r][c];`. The `c + index` shifts the column to the right. However, the `% x[0].length` handles wrapping the columns around to the start of the row, if necessary.

Comment: thanks @mook, i got the idea. if i change the column index then that column should start from last.

Comment: @RehanKhan No problem, glad I could help. In the future, it is better to show some example of what you have tried though, but I let it slide this time  :)

Comment: @RehanKhan I'm not sure what you're saying about changing the column index though...just change `index` and it will change how far the elements rotate.

Comment: Thanks @mook, i mean if i change column index then all column elements of that index should start from last.

Comment: @RehanKhan I'm still not sure what you're saying, but as long as you have it figured out, that's okay. Is there a reason you unaccepted my answer and didn't vote on it?

Comment: Thanks @mook, if index =2 then array of Y should be { {  4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3 }, 
              { 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3 },
              { 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3 },
              { 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3 } };   thanks once again i will do..

Comment: @RehanKhan How is that different than if `index = 3`? You can make `x` and `index` whatever you want and it will work. Well, at least as long as `x` is non-empty and is a rectangular 2D array (each row has the same number of elements).

Comment: Thanks @mook, but if i put index=7, it should be throw Exception(Index out of bound Exception).

Comment: `index = 7` works fine for me with the code in my answer. Did you copy it exactly?